# The program has unexpectedly finished when using static 2D vector with struct

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to std::cout out my 2D vector struct. When I run my program, it unexpectedly finishes.

I am trying to use the players vector in my MainWindow class. Any ideas?

**datacapture.h**

```
class datacapture
{
public:
    static vector<vector<GameInfo>> players;
};
```

**datacapture.cpp**

```
vector<GameInfo> games;
vector<vector<GameInfo>> datacapture::players;
...
cout << datacapture::players[0][0].Name << endl;
```

Comment: You can only use `operator[]` to access elements of a vector that exist.  And a `std::vector` constructed with a default constructor has no elements, so you cannot use `operator[]` on it at all.  You need to create some, by passing a size to the constructor or calling `resize()`, `push_back()`, etc.

Comment: There are languages where doing something like `array[3] = x` will enlarge the array to contain at least 4 elements.  C++ is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you `datacapture::players[0]`, you're getting a reference to the first element of `datacapture::players`. The problem is that you didn't add any elements!

To diagnose this type of problem without asking on Stack Overflow, you can use the address sanitizer gcc flags or run your program using valgrind. If it's throwing a segmentation fault, you could catch that using gdb. Another way you could catch this is by using `datacapture::players.at(0).at(0).Name` instead of the `[]` notation. `.at` checks the bounds first and would notice that there are no elements (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

First, create an element, then use it. Maybe something like this:

```cpp
GameInfo game; // Initialize properly here
vector<GameInfo> games {game};
vector<vector<GameInfo>> datacapture::players {games};
...
cout << datacapture::players.at(0).at(0).Name << endl;
```